# add json object to Java HttpGet request to C# WebApi

Tags: java, c#, android, json, asp.net-web-api

i'm trying to send json object from java client to C# WebApi, but the input parameter is null.
the java code:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Gson gson = new Gson();  
    String json = gson.toJson(per);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("person", json.toString()));
    HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://naviserver.azurewebsites.net/api/Person/Get?" + URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, "UTF-8"));
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader(
                "Authorization",
                "Bearer TokenRemovedBecauseUseless");


        org.apache.http.HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

the WebApi method:

```
    public List<String> Get([FromUri]Person person)
    {}
```

can someone tell me how to send json object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the WebApi is not expecting the person object in JSON format. By using FromUri with a complex object, it is expecting that the url with have a query parameter for each field in Person.

There is a nice example [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/) about how it works.

Basically you will want your query parameters to look like this:

http://naviserver.azurewebsites.net/api/Person/Get?name=dave&age=30

and in Java:

```
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", person.getName()));
qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", String.valueOf(person.getAge())));
```

If you want to send the person in JSON format, a better way would be to use a HTTP POST and set the JSON in the body. Then in the WebApi, your method would look like this:

public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Person person)

You will then also have to change your Java client to send a POST request.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://naviserver.azurewebsites.net/api/Person");
Person person = new Person("dave", 30);
Gson gson = new Gson();  
String json = gson.toJson(person);
StringEntity body = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(body);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: and if i have another field in Person: "List<String> childrens" how to send it in GET request? if i'm using POST i'm getting 405 error...

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a good way to send a list nested inside of a complex object. If you changed to the post, you will also need to change the Java client to a post. I have updated the answer to also show the Java changes needed.